# LINQ Equivalent of SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have to translate the following SQL Query into LINQ equivalent

```
SELECT 
    0 AS DOCID, 
    'All_Forms ' as PAGE, 
    0 AS PAGENUMBER

UNION 

SELECT 
    DOCID,
    (CAST(IsNull(CUSTOMPAGE,PAGENUMBER) AS VARCHAR(10)) +'. '+TITLE ) AS PAGE,
    PAGENUMBER FROM Medical_Reports 
WHERE
    PAPERSTYLE='Normal' 
    AND PAGENUMBER<>10000 
ORDER BY
    docid
```

How to translate the above into LINQ equivalents?

Comment: That's invalid SQL, the `FROM` is missing on the first part of the union.

Comment: @Abel: You don't need a from clause, it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @Abel,No if you execute it in Sql Server you will get the result

Comment: Aha, ok, then that's changed or I'm poised with bugs in some other SQL dialect...

Comment: @Abel: Perhaps you're thinking of Oracle's "FROM DUAL" clause.

Comment: @Jeff Mattfield and others: no, it's just UNION. I cannot see any reference, on [MSDN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29), on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) or even [Sql-Tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-union-sql-tutorial/) that shows somehow that the `FROM` can be discarded. I tried with SQL Server 2008 and cannot get it to work withour `FROM` on either side.

Comment: @Abel: Interesting. I can't seem to get it to work *with* a FROM clause. The MSDN reference for the FROM clause states that it can be omitted for SELECT statements that have no column names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've taken care of the union in your database and retrieve your data through a view, it could be this:

```
from reports in medicalReports
where reports.PaperStyle == "Normal"
&& reports.PageNumber != 10000
order by reports.DocId
select reports
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var reps = from r in Medical_Reports
               where r.PaperStyle  == 'Normal' && r.PageNumber != 10000
               order by r.DocId
           select { DocId = r.DocId,
                    Page = ((string)(r.CustomPage == r.PageNumber) + ". " + r.Title,
                    PageNumber = r.PageNumber };

reps.Add({ DocId = 0, Page = "All_Forms ", PageNumber = 0 });
```

Note: completely untested code. No guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this with a hastily-made table based on your SQL. I hope it's what you're looking for:

```
var firstItem = new List<dynamic>() { 
    new { DocId = 0, Page = "All_Forms ", PageNumber = 0}
};

var pages = (from p1 in firstItem
             select p1).Union(
             from p2 in MedicalReports
             where p2.PaperStyle == "Normal" &&
                    p2.PageNumber != 10000
             orderby p2.DocId
             select new
             {
                 DocId = p2.DocId,
                 Page = ((p2.CustomPage != null) ? p2.CustomPage : p2.PageNumber.ToString()) + ". " + p2.Title,
                 PageNumber = p2.PageNumber
             });
```